# Flush issue in shared memory

Tags: c, ipc

Suppose a parent process forks a child process and they will be sharing a data block through shared memory (`shm_open`), do we have to consider the data flushing such that every time the child process modifies the shared memory the parent process can immediately know?

```
/* Parent */
int fd = shm_open(...)
void seg = mmap(...)
... // clear all data in seg
while(seg->data == true) {
  // flush here so that the parent won't keep reading data from register?
}

/* Child*/
int fd 
int fd = shm_open(...)
void seg = mmap(...)
seg->data = true;
```

If flushing is necessary, what would be a solution look like?

Comment: If you're using memory shared between threads, the answer is C11's `_Atomic`, which includes *ordered atomics*, inter-threads happens-before. Processes are not quite as well-specified, though C11 *recommends* that atomics be address-free, in which case you can use the atomics between processes as well.